# Pandas: Extract top (n) values from DataFrame matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix

This is a problem that arose when calculating the frequency of co-occurrence.

I have Dataframe that 884x884 matrix with rows and columns symmetrical.

I'd like to extract the top 20 values from the elements of this matrix.

However, if I sort down columns or rows, only one column or rows reacts.
please help me

```
        alexa  actual  afford  alarm  alway  dot  ask  app  amazon
alexa       0       9       4      7      7   49   30   10      17
actual      9       0       2      2      1   26    6    1       0
afford      4       2       0      0      0    3    1    0       0
alarm       7       2       0      0      0   15   10    4       1
alway       7       1       0      0      0    3    0    4       0
dot        49      26       3     15      3    0   42   16      25
ask        30       6       1     10      0   42    0    6      11
app        10       1       0      4      4   16    6    0       6
amazon     17       0       0      1      0   25   11    6       0
```

this is example dataframe

may be i want extract top 2 value,

output : ((alexa,dot),49),((dot,ask),42)

Comment: Are you looking for something like `df.head(20)`?  This will let you preview the first 20 rows.  If not, please provide an example of your DataFrame and the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try; although I'm sure there are more elegant ways to accomplish this.

Using your DataFrame as above (called `df`):

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

# Create a list of unique combinations (e.g. (alexa, actual)).
groups = list(itertools.combinations(df.columns, 2))

# Collect the count for each combination.
data = [('_'.join(group), df.loc[group]) for group in groups]

# Populate a new DataFrame with the counts and sort.
dfx = (pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['group', 'count'])
       .sort_values('count', ascending=False)
       .reset_index(drop=True))

# Display the top (n) values.
dfx.head(5)
```

#### Output:

```
        group  count
0   alexa_dot     49
1     dot_ask     42
2   alexa_ask     30
3  actual_dot     26
4  dot_amazon     25
```

Hope this helps!